# Iphone create uibarbutton without interface builder

Tags: iphone, camera, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

i want  creating uibarbutton without interface builder = (whit code)
and this button is style camera
please help me

Comment: i want creating in view did load

Comment: What do you mean by "this button is style camera"?

Comment: I want to create programmatically a button like the one we see on the native iphone camera application 
when you want to take a picture

Answer (score 7):

Objective-C:

```
UIBarButtonItem* cameraBarButtonItem = 
     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
     target:self action:@selector(myCameraAction)];
```

Swift:

```
let cameraBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: "myCameraAction")
```

This will create a UIBarButtonItem with the system item icon of the camera.